# Get FormField passed options within a FormEvent

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

In a Symfony project, I have a Form EventSubscriber acting on several forms.

It aims to disable each field which is already filled.

In the Subscriber when I use:

```
$childOptions = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();
```

I receive all resolved options for a child, I want to get only those passed during the form building. (Because form some FormTypes (i.o. DocumentType) it is not possible to reinject all resolved options, some of them causes troubles).

- A FormType example :

  ```
  class FooType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->add('entity',EntityType::class,array( 
                          'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                          'choice_label' => 'username',
                  ))
              ->addEventSubscriber($this->changesSubscriber); // See next class
      }
  }
  ```
- The Subscriber :

  ```
  class ChangesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
  {
      // Disables filled inputs
      public function postSetData(FormEvent $event)
      {
          $form = $event->getForm();

          foreach($form->all() as $child)
          {
              $childName = $child->getName();
              $childType = $child->getConfig()->getType()->getName();

              // Here I receive all resolved options
              // But I only want the options passed above during 'buildForm' ('class','choice_label') :
              $childOptions = $child->getConfig()->getOptions(); 

              if(!$child->isEmpty()){
                  $form->add($childName,$childType,array_merge($childOptions,array('disabled'=>true)));
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This is one example of many use cases, another example could be :
[Alsatian\FormBundle ExtensibleSubscriber](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/Extensions/ExtensibleSubscriber.php#L112)

-> A formsuscriber to make AJAX submitted choices acceptacles for Choice/Entity/Document Types.
At this time, as you can see, I choosed to only take a couple of resolved options, but I'm not satisfied with this solution.

Comment: Maybe you should add the subscriber on the field itself, not on the global form. `$builder->get("entity")->addEventSubscriber($this->changesSubscriber)`. you'll have to edit your subscriber accordingly, you probably won't need to loop anymore.

Comment: When the subscriber is on the child, I cannot 'recreate' the child, and then I cannot edit the options to add 'disabled'.

Comment: Have you considered using a form type extension instead of a subscriber?

Comment: I need a subscriber (or a eventlistener) to know if the data attached to the form is empty.

Comment: I opened an issue here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19337 (but you know it :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to change your approach.

Maybe make a custom form type, and some of the options to it should be the options to create the original type, similar to how `CollectionType` works.

Maybe it looks a bit like this:

`->add('entity', AjaxType::class,array(
     'ajax_type' => EntityType:class,
     'ajax_options' => [
         'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
         'choice_label' => 'username',
     ]
))`

That type can add the event that listens for the data and decides what to do.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I use such kind of form events widely to modify each type of FormTypes (text, choice, entity, document, ...). That's why I wrote a feature request to symfony. Then it would be easier to directly get the 'passed' option if they were saved somewhere during the form building.